# Ionic 2 creating pipes

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to create a pipe to alphabatically order an array of object. But, its not working.

Here's my pipe code (.ts):

```
import { Injectable, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

    /*
      Generated class for the AlplabeticOrdering pipe.

      See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html for more info on
      Angular 2 Pipes.
    */
    @Pipe({
      name: 'alplabetic-ordering'
    })
    @Injectable()
    export class AlplabeticOrdering {
      /*
        Takes a value and makes it lowercase.
       */
      transform(friendsName, args:any[]) {

        var frName=[];
        frName.push(friendsName);

        return frName.sort();
      }
    }
```

and here in the html where I have called the filter:

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let f of dataArray | alplabetic-ordering:f;">
```

Here's a snippet of error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("
  </ion-refresher> -->
<ion-list *ngIf="pageType == 1">
  <ion-item [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let f of dataArray | alplabetic-ordering:f;">
    <ion-avatar item-left (click)="viewFriendsP"): FriendsListing@5:12
Parser Error: Unexpected token -, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 32 in [let f of dataArray | alplabetic-ordering:f;] in FriendsListing@5:12 (" == 1">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let f of dataArray | alplabetic-ordering:f;">
    <ion-avatar item-left [ERROR ->](click)="viewFriendsProfile()">
        <img [src]="f.imgURL">
    </ion-avatar>
"): FriendsListing@6:26
Parser Error: Unexpected token -, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 32 in [let f of dataArray | alplabetic-ordering:f;] in FriendsListing@5:12 ("y | alplabetic-ordering:f;">
    <ion-avatar item-left (click)="viewFriendsProfile()">
        <img [ERROR ->][src]="f.imgURL">
    </ion-avatar>
```

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined (" .. it looks like error is elsewhere

Comment: I fixed this particular error. But, not working yet.

Comment: Your pipe keyword has a `-`. Use single quotes `'alplabetic-ordering'` in html